# sql select orders not containing certain items

Tags: mysql, sql

The database has 3 tables, "items", "orders" and "orderitems" which represent an N:N relation. I need to find the orders that doesn't contain certain items. For example, I want to get all the orders that doesn't include apples, oranges, or bananas.

I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM orders o, 
LEFT JOIN orderitems oi ON o.order_id=oi.order_id
LEFT JOIN items i ON oi.item_id=i.item_id
WHERE
   i.name NOT IN ('banana', 'apple', 'orange')
```

It doesn't work. It returns all orders as long as they include at least an item different from 'banana', 'apple' and 'orange'.

I thought about doing a "NOT IN" a subselect of all orders containing those items, but it would be very slow because the subselect would be getting almost all orders (several millions of results).

Comment: A bit confusing - maybe some sample data?

Comment: have you tried `not exists` instead of `not in`?

Comment: Interesting, although it looks like `not exists` takes the exact same time as `not in`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Please try:

```
SELECT * FROM orders o
WHERE o.order_id
  NOT IN
  (
        SELECT oi.order_id 
        FROM orderitems oi 
        INNER JOIN items i ON oi.item_id=i.item_id
        WHERE
           i.name IN ('banana', 'apple', 'orange')

    )
```

Comment: That's the approach I mentioned in my question ("NOT IN" subselect). The problem is 99% of the orders contain any of those items so Mysql would need to store the result of the subselect on a tmp table and it would be too slow.

Comment: In our scenario it's faster than Gordon Linoff's solution.

Comment: I'm glad it somehow occured useful though as far as I"ve seen @Gordon Linoff's answers I think he has wide knowledge and experience in the subject. Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT oi.order_id
FROM orderitems oi JOIN
     items i
     ON oi.item_id=i.item_id
GROUP BY oi.order_id
HAVING SUM(i.name IN ('banana', 'apple', 'orange')) = 0;
```

If you want the full order information you can can join the `orders` table back in.

Comment: But why poster query doesn't work .   I dont see any error of `i.name NOT IN ('banana', 'apple', 'orange')` in `where` condition

Comment: @imran . . . I think the OP explains it pretty well.  That query will return orders as long as they contain something different from those three items.  This version will guarantee that an order has none of those three items.  The logic is different.

Comment: It works, and the logic is clear but it's even slower than the "NOT IN" approach. Is there a way to not need a temporary table?

Comment: @FranciscoR . . . What temporary table?

Comment: temporary storage on disk, sorry. Result is too big to be stored in memory. EXPLAIN says "using temporary. using filesort". That query takes more than 3 minutes while the "NOT IN" query takes 8 seconds.

Comment: @FranciscoR . . . The queries are doing different things.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
select *
  from orders o
  left join (select o.order_id
               from orders o
               join orderitems oi
                 on o.order_id = oi.order_id
               join items i
                 on oi.item_id = i.item_id
              where i.name in ('banana', 'apple', 'orange')) v
    on o.order_id = v.order_id
  left join orderitems oi
    on o.order_id = oi.order_id
  left join items i
    on oi.item_id = i.item_id
 where v.order_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to get all orders that do have the items you are looking at and then exclude those orders from your result set.

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders o
    LEFT JOIN (select order_id 
                from orderitems oi 
                    inner join items i ON oi.item_id=i.item_id
                WHERE i.name IN ('banana', 'apple', 'orange')
                ) x
        ON o.order_id=x.order_id
WHERE x.order_id is null
```